# Retrieving auto-incremented column value in ASP.NET from mySQL table WITHOUT using stored proceedure

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database

I a function that used a mySQL Data Adapter and inserts a new row.

I want the function to return the value of the auto-incremented column of the updated row.

Please help.

```
Public Function addRow(ByVal colA as String, ByVal colB as String) As Integer
    Dim dbConnection As New MySqlConnection("server=xxx; user id=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxx; pooling=false;")
    Dim dbDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", dbConnection)
    Dim dbDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dbDataAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet, "table")

    Dim dbNewRow As DataRow = dbDataSet.Tables("table").NewRow
    dbNewRow("colA") = colA
    dbNewRow("colB") = colB

    dbDataSet.Tables("table").Rows.Add(dbNewRow)

    dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT into table(colA, colB) VALUES (@colA, @colB)", dbConnection)
    dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("colA", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 256, "colA")
    dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("colB", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 256, "colB")

    Dim dbParm As MySqlParameter = dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@colID", MySqlDbType.Int16, 16, "colID")
    dbParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

    dbDataAdapter.Update(dbDataSet, "table")

    Return dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters("@colID").Value

End Function
```

### The "Return..." line doesn't work and don't know what the correct code would be.

Comment: All I get is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself again.

```
Public Function addRow(ByVal colA as String, ByVal colB as String) As Integer 
    Dim dbConnection As New MySqlConnection("server=xxx; user id=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxx; pooling=false;") 
    Dim dbDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table where colID = 0", dbConnection) 
    Dim dbDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet 
    dbDataAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet, "table") 

    Dim dbNewRow As DataRow = dbDataSet.Tables("table").NewRow 
    dbNewRow("colA") = colA 
    dbNewRow("colB") = colB 

    dbDataSet.Tables("table").Rows.Add(dbNewRow) 

    dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT into table(colA, colB) VALUES (@colA, @colB); Select * from table where colID = LAST_INSERT_ID()", dbConnection) 
    dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("colA", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 256, "colA") 
    dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("colB", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 256, "colB") 

    dbDataAdapter.Update(dbDataSet, "table") 

    Return dbDataSet.Tables("table").Rows(0).Item(0)

End Function
```

Seems all I needed to do was add a Select statement on the end of the Insert statement and use the LAST_INSERT_ID function to just get the last Inserted row. Then just read from that one rows ID and return it.

I am quite disappointed that DataAdapters work this way. I'm sure classic ASP was easier than this! Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the insert stored procedure is doing something like

```
RETURN @@IDENTITY
```

You will need the equivalent of this:

```
oDatabase.AddParameter(oDbCommand, "@RETURN_VALUE", System.Data.DbType.Int32, System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, null);
...
oDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
returnStatusCode = (int)oDbCommand.Parameters[0].Value;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I am not using a stored procedure. Is the only way to do this to use one?

Comment: I think the inline SQL that you are using can still use the "RETURN @@IDENTIY" statement instead of the select statement, which will return the primary key of the column assuming you have it set as an identity column, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim result As Integer = 0
Integer.TryParse(dbDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters("@colID").Value, result)
Return result
```

Comment: Well, then @colID is not an Integer.

Comment: I have tried returning a string but the value is Null. It is not getting any value from @colID.